# Anyone know where I can find the structure definition of the optional header of a 32bit executable? I can't seem to find it in the winnt.h file

Tags: portable-executable

I was able to locate the DOS header, NT header and file header of Portable Executables in the winnt.h file. I wasn't able to locate the definition of optional headers using the find function in Notepad++.

If anyone knows where this is defined, some assistance would greatly be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The PE format is widely known and is already [officially documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format). But PE is a binary file, why do you want to open and search it with Notepad++

Comment: It is in winnt.h as well.  There are two flavors of it, 32-bit vs 64-bit.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-image_optional_header32

Comment: @phuclv I'm teaching myself programming by looking at structures of files. I've studied and made bitmaps using hex editors and now I'm transitioning into PEs. The plan is to become familiar with the file structures so I can make these files from scratch either with a hex editor or with the help of some language such as C.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks man. I was searching using a mispelt keyword. Thanks again!